# Why are infinite cardinals limit ordinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

My book states this as obvious, but it isn't so trivial to me. thanks

Comment: Can you come up with a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\alpha + 1$, where $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal?

Answer (score 24):

Recall that a cardinal is an initial ordinal, an ordinal which cannot be put in bijection into a smaller ordinal. Thanks to the Cantor-Bernstein theorem it is enough to show that there is no injection into a smaller ordinal instead.

If an infinite ordinal $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal then there is some $\beta$ such that $\alpha=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$.

The map $g\colon\alpha\to\beta$ defined as: $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=\beta\\x+1 & x<\omega\\x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is injective from $\alpha$ into a smaller ordinal, and therefore $\alpha$ cannot be an initial ordinal, that is a cardinal.

Answer (score 15):

They are **ordinals** by definition, because we *choose* to use initial ordinals as the canonical representative of each class of sets-with-the-same-cardinality. This choice could in principle have been made differently, but it turns out to be a useful convention (though it only works in when we have the Axiom of Choice).

They are **limit** ordinals, because (except for 0) limit ordinals are precisely the ordinals that are not successor ordinals. And an infinite successor ordinal always has the same cardinality as the one it is a successor of (you can make a bijection that moves the last element away into the initial $\omega$ segment with the standard Hilberts-Hotel trick), so a successor ordinal is never the *first* ordinal with a given cardinality.

(On the other hand, beware that not *all* limit ordinals are cardinals).